# How can I view a compressed file content

Tags: linux

I have a very large file as: `filename.bz2`, how can I view the file content and do some commands like `awk` to extract some data into another file without decompress it ? I tried `head -50 filename.bz2` to view the first 50 lines, but it prints out rubbish and not the what I supposed to view from the file.

Comment: you cannot view only some content. You have to extract it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `bzcat` and pipe its output to `awk` or whatever tool you use, but it is essentially nothing different from extracting a file and then processing it.

```
$ echo '1' > test
$ bzip2 test
$ bzcat test.bz2
1
```

Comment: "it is essentially nothing different from extracting a file and then processing it" -- I agree if you need to process the whole file. If you only need to see part of it though (as might be the case for the OP, since they want to take the head), then this is great for large files, as you don't need to decompress the whole thing.

Comment: It is essentially very different though in that the decompressing takes up no storage space.

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried bzcat?

```
bzcat filename.bz2 | head -50
```

Read [more](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_bzcat.htm)